# Delete Cookie when user manually delete from the browser

Tags: php, cookies

Is there any way to delete cookie until user will go to manually delete from the browser in PHP

Comment: Can you rephrase this question so it's more detailed (and properly worded) ? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: No need to delete it manually.

Comment: check @fluty's comment, i've mentioned there

Answer (score 1):

Since cookies are stored on client side and browser send cookie in request header,
so if user delete cookie from browser then your script will not receive that cookie
and hence you need not to delete from server side in this particular scenario.

Comment: i have a search option in my website, and when user search something there then i'll keep search words store in cookie, that's what i done already but i want when user close the browser and come back again i want to show the previous search words again, that's what i want.

Comment: @JassiOberoi you can set cookie with long expiration time.

Comment: setcookie("cookie", "value", time()+x*3600*24);,This will set your cookie for x number of days

Answer (score 0):

You can unset it:

```
<?php
    unset($_COOKIE['myCookie']);
?>
```

or you can set a past time for it:

```
<?php
    setcookie("myCookie", "", time() - 3600);
?>
```

In other words, you can delete a `cookie` only if your domain has set it.

Comment: Mihai i don't want to delete cookie from the backend what i want is user will delete cookie from the browser

Comment: Don't understand .. what do you want ?

Comment: Cookies will delete when user delete by self.

Comment: Yes, user can delete at any moment a cookie, thay can even change it's value, you cannot do anything about it ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes its

```
 unset($_COOKIE['myCookie']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

to delete the cookie you would do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="eraseCookie('GuessName');">delete</a>
```